# Currently trying to learn Microsoft.net core, but it is giving this error Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

This is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":"Data Source=DatingApp.db "
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And the Startupclass:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

           services.AddControllers();     

        }
```

I am trying to "dotnet ef database update" but it still giving me this error
I searched the problem and tried all the solution. If anyone can help me it would be so good!

Comment: Which version of .net core are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.1.201

Comment: Hi, can you give more code of your startup function? I am speculating there is something wrong with your configuration

Comment: Hello! I restarted the aplication because it was giving me the same error, no matter what I was doing. Thank you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are don't have empty connection string in your environment-based settings file.

By default asp.net core project template create multiple settings file `appsettings.json` and
`appsettings.Development.json` based on current `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` env var.

Also you can check current `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value in your system.
Run `echo %ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT%`

So one of the possible error that you've added your connection string in wrong file or have empty one in env-based settings.

Comment: Sorry, I am quiet the noob. Can you be more concise and tell me exactly where I should look in the project?